# Getting started with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I'm new to Tensorflow and trying to run the example codes, and I just can't understand what happening in this program :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
# NumPy is often used to load, manipulate and preprocess data.
import numpy as np

# Declare list of features. We only have one real-valued feature. There are many
# other types of columns that are more complicated and useful.
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]

# An estimator is the front end to invoke training (fitting) and evaluation
# (inference). There are many predefined types like linear regression,
# logistic regression, linear classification, logistic classification, and
# many neural network classifiers and regressors. The following code
# provides an estimator that does linear regression.
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

# TensorFlow provides many helper methods to read and set up data sets.
# Here we use `numpy_input_fn`. We have to tell the function how many batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,
                                              num_epochs=1000)

# We can invoke 1000 training steps by invoking the `fit` method and passing the
# training data set.
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

# Here we evaluate how well our model did. In a real example, we would want
# to use a separate validation and testing data set to avoid overfitting.
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
```

Can any one explain to what happens starting from the `input_fn` line.
Is the `batch_size` the size of the input data ? and why do I need the `num_epochs` since I tell the  estimator the it needs 1000 steps ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TensorFlow.  The line below: 
 `input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,
                                              num_epochs=1000)`
 generates a function `input_fn` which is later passed to the method `.fit` for your estimator object which was generated with the Linear Regressor Estimator. The `input_fn` will provide `batch_size=4` features and targets up to 1000 times (`num_epochs=1000`).  `batch_size` refers to the mini-batch size.  On Epoch is a complete run through your training examples.  In this case, there are only 4 examples in the training data provided by this `input_fn`.
This is a guffy example since Stochastic Gradient Decent is unnecessary to solve this linear regression problem, but is shows you the mechanisms that are necessary for solving tougher problems.